# sending a file to client in java

Tags: java, file-upload, client-server

i'm new to java. I'm trying to create a simple java file server from where the clients can request for a file and download it. basically when a client requests for a file it will simply will be written from server's folder to client folder. When i run my code it does not show any error but the file that client requested is not written to it's folder either.

my client side code:

```
public void download(Socket s) throws Exception {
     DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
     DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
     BufferedReader con = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    System.out.print("Enter File Name :");
    String request = con.readLine();
    w.println(request);
    String msg = r.readLine();
    if (msg.startsWith("ERROR")) {
        System.out.println("File not found on Server ...");
        return;
    } else if (msg.startsWith("FOUND")) {
        System.out.println("Receiving File ...");
        File f = new File(request);
        if (f.exists()) {
            String Option;
            System.out.println("File Already Exists. Want to OverWrite (Y/N) ?");
            Option = con.readLine();
            if (Option == "N") {
                dout.flush();
                return;
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(f);
        int ch;
        String temp;
        do {
            temp = din.readLine();
            ch = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            if (ch != -1) {
                fileout.write(ch);
            }
        } while (ch != -1);
        fileout.close();
        System.out.println(din.readLine());
    }
}
```

The server side:

```
public class Fileagent extends Thread {

    Socket client;
    DataInputStream din;
    DataOutputStream dout;
    ServerSocket soc;
    PrintWriter w;
    BufferedReader r;

    public Fileagent(Socket soc) {
        try {
            client = soc;
            din = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            w = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader con = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("FTP Client Connected ...");
            start();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    public void upload() throws Exception {


        w.println("SEnding.....");
        String file = r.readLine();
        File f = new File(file);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            w.println("ERROR");
            return;
        } else {
            w.println("FOUND");
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
            int ch;
            do {
                ch = fin.read();
                w.println(String.valueOf(ch));
            } while (ch != -1);
            fin.close();
        }
```

I'm trying to send simple text files but the files is not being send to clients.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should spend more time on your code format to make it more readable.

Comment: You should make your variable names more descriptive than just `w`, `r`,...

Comment: Do you need to send each byte as a number on each line of its own?  What happens when you `telnet` to your server and give it a file name?

Comment: code has been edited. and when i give the server a file name, it keeps coming back to it's (server's) main method.

Comment: Your client does never use the socket... how do you download the file?

Comment: BTW: Is it about download (server > client) or upload (client > server)? Your code seems to describe upload functionality?

Comment: @home it would seem logical that whenever the client downloads, the server must upload, doesn't it?

Comment: @glowcoder: of course... nevertheless, the client does not work with the socket at all, I just do not find the snippet accessing the 'upload' funtion (maybe I'm blind?). It's just local file operations.

Comment: @home yeah that was my conclusion too. I mean without getting his whole codebase and setting it up I can't say (who knows what `con` is? etc..) but that seems to be what I feel the problem is too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you are not flushing your `PrintWriter` after sending the request from the client to the server:

```
w.println(request);
w.flush();
```

You seem to be using a `PrintWriter` on the server side as well.  Make sure to call `w.flush()` or `w.close()` when you are done sending stuff over.

Also, I assume you realize that this is an extremely inefficient way to send the file over.

Comment: thanks..can u please suggest how to send file in more efficient way.an example will be great.

Comment: You could just return the file bytes directly.  The server would write a 0 byte if file did not exist otherwise write a 1 byte and then the raw byte contents of the file.  The client would read a byte and if 1 then it would read blocks of 1024 or something and write them out to the file.

Comment: Thought I'd just tweak your code.  Client here http://pastebin.com/UcA93J1p and server here http://pastebin.com/BsaGqMdt

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem stems from this

```
String request=con.readLine();
```

You're always reading from this `con` object. But you're passing in a `Socket s` to the method.

There are other problems, such as what Gray mentioned, and also that you're writing each character on its own line, but those are just messed up formatting; they shouldn't prevent you from getting a file at all...

Comment: can you tell me the difference between readUTF() and readLine. Thanks